# macos: After starting apache, the port and DocumentRoot are wrong

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

Apache used to work on my machine, last night I stopped it and now I can't get it to work again.

I have an `index.html` in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, which is also what's set as `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. In this file, there is only the word `TEST`. There's nothing else in the directory.
I started apache with `sudo apachectl start`, which didn't produce an error message.

Still, on `localhost:80` I get a connection error. Interestingly, when I go to `localhost:8080`, I get the standard apache 'It works' message. This ceases to work when I stop apache with `sudo apachectl stop`. Tried this in multiple browsers with clearing the cache, so that's not the issue.

I grepped the entire `/etc/apache2` directory for a mention of 8080, no results. I'm starting to think I'm not running the program I expect, or another version that is configured somewhere else. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any apache config files in `/usr/local/etc/`?

Comment: @DSchlachter yes! so that's where the config comes from. Does that mean I have apache installed twice? How do it tell it to use the config from /etc/apache2/httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see which configuration file is being used, you need to see where apache is running from, then run it with the `-V` option to see its configuration options. This one-liner will find a running apache process and print the configuration:

```
$(ps ax -o comm | grep -m 1 '[a]pache\|[h]ttpd') -V
```

The configuration file location is on the line `D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`. Mine is at `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

The location of the configuration file is set when Apache is compiled. However, you can change this by passing the `-f` option to Apache [when it starts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/invoking.html).

Apache on your system is probably started by launchd. You might find the right `plist` file using this:

```
grep -lRi 'httpd\|apache' /Library/Launch*/ ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

I have a `plist` that loads apache in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd22.plist`.

To specify a different configuration file you'd need to edit the program arguments to pass the `-f` option with the configuration file path, e.g.

```
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/httpd22/bin/httpd</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>FOREGROUND</string>
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/path/to/httpd.conf</string>
  </array>
```

Rebooting would apply the changes.